# Can't save model using F expression

Tags: django, python-3.4

I'm using *F expressions* to update some of my model fields.
I want to do it using specific custom model methods, but it's not working.

This is my model

```
class SingletonModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__class__.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).delete()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        try:
            return cls.objects.get()
        except cls.DoesNotExist:
            return cls()

class Folios(SingletonModel):
    _folios = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, db_column='folios')
    fecha_ultima_compra = models.DateTimeField()
    fecha_ultima_venta = models.DateTimeField()

    def agregar_folios(self, valor):
        self.fecha_ultima_compra = timezone.now()
        self._folios=models.F('folios') + valor
        self.save()

    def sustraer_folios(self, valor):
        self.fecha_ultimo_venta = timezone.now()
        self._folios=models.F('folios') - valor
        self.save()
```

And when I do

```
f = Folios.load()
f.agregar_folios(200)
```

I get the Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  ... Some more info
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'CombinedExpression'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I had to check if there was an existing record in db first

```
def agregar_folios(self, valor):
    self.fecha_ultima_compra = timezone.now()
    if self.pk is not None:
        self._folios = models.F('folios') + valor
    else:
        self._folios = valor
    self.save()

def sustraer_folios(self, valor):
    self.fecha_ultimo_venta = timezone.now()
    if self.pk is not None:
        self._folios = models.F('folios') - valor
    else:
        self._folios = valor
    self.save()
```